# Fragment gets added each time after restart (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

The fragments that I add to FragmentManager gets doubled each time I restart the activity, without destroying the previous fragments from the FragmentManager.
Here is my code:

```
private FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment5, "5").hide(fragment5).commit();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment4, "4").hide(fragment4).commit();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment3, "3").hide(fragment3).commit();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment1, "1").commit();
}
```

I understood that the fragment get added repeatedly when the methods in the fragments were called twice. But to check if it is actually the problem with the FragmentManager, I called the getFragments method

```
TextView someText = findViewById(R.id.text);
someText.setText(""+fm.getFragments());
```

and set it to TextView, right after the last transaction. The first time when the app is loaded, the TextView is empty. The second time when I use the 'Apply changes and restart activity', the TextView shows the fragments array list only once.. but the fragments get doubled. The third time the TextView shows the fragments array list twice and the fragments get tripled.
 Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong? Hope you will answer. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

try these solutions

1. Initialize fragment manager before these lines in onCreate method.
2. try to popup the fragment on backpress
3. don't add all fragmnets at once. only add the fragment when it needs to be added.

Comment: But I do not add the fragments to backstack. So nothing works on backpress. I am just hiding and showing the fragments.

Comment: fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

Comment: try to understand the activity lifecycle and you will get it.

Comment: Sorry but the result is same as before.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it like this

```
private FragmentManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity);
fm = getSupportFragmentManager();


fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment5, "5").hide(fragment5).commit();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment4, "4").hide(fragment4).commit();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment3, "3").hide(fragment3).commit();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment1, "1").commit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I have tried this and it works the same. I think this is a bug in the fragments. I have reported it and am waiting for their reply.